# run powershell schedule task info request without admin rights

Tags: php, powershell

Hey guys i wrote a little powershell script which outputs infos about all schedule tasks in Json format. This information i use for a small website. This is my powershell script:

```
$servername = "localhost"
$schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
$schedule.connect($servername)
$tasks = $schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)
$tasks |select name, lasttaskresult, lastruntime, enabled, nextruntime | ConvertTo-Json > C:\xampp\htdocs\batch_files\test.txt
```

I am running the `ps1` file from PHP with this line:

```
$output = shell_exec('powershell.exe -command C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\batch_files\\stask_query.ps1');
```

But this doesn't work. When i run the script from the powershell console i am getting a access denied error. When i run it in a console started with `Run as admin` it is working. How can i get this done?

I have tried to add the apache service user to the powershell with full rights with this line:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -showSecurityDescriptorUI
```

But it doesn't help.

EDIT: I noticed i don't need `$servername` updated script:

```
$schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
$schedule.connect()
$tasks = $schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)
$tasks |select name, lasttaskresult, lastruntime, enabled, nextruntime | ConvertTo-Json > C:\xampp\htdocs\batch_files\test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working with following command:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell -showSecurityDescriptorUI
```

there i added the apache service user with full rights.

Than i needed to run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

In the x86 powershell. The system is running on a 64bit system and the service is running the powershell in 32bit mode and i changed the execution policy only in the 64bit mode.